# Universal impl for all T, &T, &mut T, [T], &[T], *mut T

Tags: rust

Consider this code:

```
pub trait Hello {
    fn hello(&self);
}

impl Hello for Any {
    fn hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello!!!!!");
    }
}
```

I remember seeing somewhere that there was a new feature in Rust that lets you implement a function that is directly accessible for all objects like this:

```
let foo = 0 as u8;
foo.hello();
```

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find it. Is there actually a global/universal "implementor"?

Comment: Note that `impl Hello for Any` actually means `impl Hello for dyn Any`, i.e. it implements the `Hello` trait for trait objects of the `Any` trait. If you want to call this on an object, you first need to cast it to a trait object, like `(&foo as &dyn Any).hello()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could make a generic implementation of your trait:

```
pub trait Hello {
    fn hello(&self);
}

impl<T> Hello for T {
    fn hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello!!!!!");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = 0 as u8;
    foo.hello();
    let bar = "world!".to_string();
    bar.hello();
}
```

Note that Rust currently does not allow specialization of generics (although there is an [open RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) on it) so your trait implementation has to work as-is for any T.